# Find best label position group of coordinates/polygon

Tags: .net, vb.net, algorithm, math, polygon

I have a sitiation where I want to place a pointer on a map.
The problem is how to calculate the position of this pointer in vb.Net.

I can have 3 sitiations:

1. A single point
2. A way point, 2 or more points
3. A polygon, multiple points

All points are latitude and longitudes. Now I want to place a marker for these situations.

1. Is simple, the marker position is the point
2. The marker should be in the middle of the line
3. The polygon is the hardest. I can find the centroid (point of gravity) of it, but that can be outside the polygon. So that has no use for a marker.

I have no idea how to calculate these points (exept for nr.1 ;-))

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the polygon does not self-intersect, you could:

1. Triangulate the polygon somehow.  [This can be done in O(n log n) time.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation)
2. Pick one of the triangles to be a "representative".  My suggestion: the triangle with the largest area, or the triangle whose smallest angle is the largest, or the triangle whose centroid is closest to the centroid of the points.
3. Use the centroid of this triangle, which must be inside the triangle and therefore inside the polygon.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a library that does all the magic: [NetTopologySuite](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite) 
You can install it as a Nuget package and the documentation is [here](http://nts.sourceforge.net/docs/v1.2/)
After getting the package it is simple.

**Center inside a polygon:**

First create a polygon by adding all your latitude and longitudes to an coordinates array.

```
'The first point needs to be the last point so it becomes a closed shape
'Becouse I loop through all my coordinates I set a flag for the first point
'so I can add it at the end
Dim firstPoint As GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate = Nothing

'create an coordinatearray
Dim coordinates() As GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate = {}

 'Loop trough all the coordinates you have (you can do a dataset loop etc)
 'For the example the coordinates are in a pointF array
 For Each Point As PointF In points

     'Save the first point so we can add it in the end
     If firstPoint Is Nothing Then
          firstPoint = New GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate(Point.X, Point.Y)
     End If

     'Create a coordinate so we can add it to the coordinate array
     Dim coordinate As New GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate(Point.X, Point.Y)

     'Adding it to the array
     Array.Resize(coordinates, coordinates.Length + 1)
     coordinates(coordinates.Length - 1) = coordinate
 Next

 'Now all the coordinates are in the array we need to add the first one at the end
 Array.Resize(coordinates, coordinates.Length + 1)
 coordinates(coordinates.Length - 1) = firstPoint


 'Now we create a linearRing with these coordinates
 Dim ring As New NetTopologySuite.Geometries.LinearRing(coordinates)

 'And use the ring to get a center point inside it
 Dim insidePoint As IPoint = ring.InteriorPoint

 'If you want a centroid you can do the following
 Dim polygon As New NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Polygon(ring)
 Dim centroidPoint As IPoint = polygon.centroid
```